# How do i create a YouTube channel without an Oops something went wrong?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

Every time I try to create a new personal channel on my personal Google account, it just makes a Brand account (which I don't wish to happen), and even when I've done everything humanly possible that I think might make the brand account 'legit' it just *won't* create the channel. I just cannot create a new channel.

In a browser it just says "Oops! Something went wrong" without indicating what.

On mobile (I don't have a cell) with an old tablet it doesn't even have the option.

I've put in plenty of information, I've identified myself over and over, I've used multiple browsers, IPs, DNS', ISPs, and meddling (enabling/disabling) with any security related to any of those things also.

Is there a secret URL or something? I've tried to inspect the page, and the network tabs aren't giving me anything my dumb brain can find.

I've looked on here and not found any answers, but have found two or three similar questions on Google's YouTube support community with no definitive answer (that works), I'm at my wits end with it.

Hope that someone can help, obviously I'm not expecting, nor feeling entitled to that, so if you have anything, I'm game to try!

If it helps, I've also managed to create channels before, even this year, I believe. Also, I guess I should say that I do not need to do this for monetary stuff.

Comment: I’m closed this question because per community consensus troubleshooting like questions are off topic

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you can only manage 5 YouTube channels (including the "owner account" that uses your Google account's name) on a single Google account. I have 5 and I just made one on another Google account without any issues.